# Google Guice desktop application - how to make it work?

Tags: java, guice, inject

I have used Guice in my web app without problems and I wanted to use it in desktop app. I am certainly missing one thing - some way to tell my app how to bind everything and know what is what. In web app, I had declaration for that in Application class, how should I do it in my desktop app?

Here is relevant code that I am using:

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule
{
   @Override
   protected void configure()
   {
   // Enable per-request-thread PersistenceManager injection.
   install(new PersistenceManagerFilter.GuiceModule());
   // Business object bindings go here.
   bind(ProjectQueries.class).to(JdoProjectQueries.class);
   bind(new TypeLiteral<Repository<Project>>() { }).to(JdoProjectRepository.class);
 }
```

My main class:

```
@Inject
public Repository<Project> projectRepo;

public void createNewProject() {
   ...
   projectRepo.persist(newProject);
}
```

I am of course getting on projectRepo.persist(newProject);

So, what else do I have to do to make it work?

EDIT:

Ok, that part work now, thanks :) It seems that I need to do a bit more though to make persistence work that way.

I am getting NPE here now:

```
public void persist(T entity) 
{ 
pmProvider.get().makePersistent(entity); 
}
```

get() returns null here

It looks like 
    install(new PersistenceManagerFilter.GuiceModule()); 
is not enough. What do I need to do? My Repository class starts with:

```
public abstract class JdoRepository<T> implements Repository<T> { 
  private final Class<T> clazz; 
  private final Provider<PersistenceManager> pmProvider; 
  protected JdoRepository(Class<T> clazz, Provider<PersistenceManager> pmProvider)    {       this.clazz = clazz; this.pmProvider = pmProvider; 
}
```

At my PMF I have:

```
public static class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule { 

  @Override protected void configure() { 
    bind(PersistenceManager.class).toProvider(new Provider<PersistenceManager>() {
      public PersistenceManager get() { 
         return PersistenceManagerFilter.pm.get(); 
         } 
      }); 
    } 
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `Bootstrap` class with main method.

Move your current static main method code to non-static one. For example `Application#run`.

Create main method in `Bootstrap` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule())
    Application app = injector.getInstance(Application.class);
    app.run();
}
```

Run `Bootstrap` class.

Comment: Ok, that solved that problems. It looks like I need to initiatie at least one more thing.

I am getting NPE here now:

     public void persist(T entity)
     {
            pmProvider.get().makePersistent(entity);
     }

Comment: It looks like
    install(new PersistenceManagerFilter.GuiceModule());
is not enough. What do I need to do?

My Repository class starts with:

    public abstract class JdoRepository<T> implements Repository<T>
    {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Provider<PersistenceManager> pmProvider;

    protected JdoRepository(Class<T> clazz,  Provider<PersistenceManager> pmProvider)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.pmProvider = pmProvider;
    }

Comment: At my PMF I have:

    public static class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            bind(PersistenceManager.class).toProvider(new Provider<PersistenceManager>()
            {
                public PersistenceManager get()
                {
                    return PersistenceManagerFilter.pm.get();
                }
            });
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Any object that is created using a Guice injector will inject objects into its properties and methods. So one way will be to create an injector in createNewProject.

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BeanModule(),.....
YourMainClass startClass = injector.getInstance(YourMainClass.class);
startClass.kickOfEveryThing();....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least ask one root object to the injector. This root object will be injected with objects, which will be injected with objects, etc. The the process needs to bootstrap.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());
Main main = injector.getInstance(Main.class);
```